# Программная блокировка экрана смартфона

Tags: java, android

Я приобрёл себе китайскую клавиатуру и возникла потребность в написании для неё "драйвера", дабы назначить клавиши. Делаю я это через `InputMethodService`.

С обычными клавишами проблем не возникло, но всё же хотелось бы добавить кнопку пробуждения/блокировки экрана. Мною было перепробовано множество подходов, но желаемого результата достичь не удалось.

Пробуждение смартфона не вызвало трудностей:

```
InputConnection ic = getCurrentInputConnection();
ic.sendKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN,KeyEvent.KEYCODE_WAKEUP))
```

Даже удалось эмулировать нажатие кнопки POWER:

```
Process mSU = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(mSU.getOutputStream());
os.writeBytes("input keyevent 26");
os.flush();
os.close();
mSU.waitFor();
```

Но, скорее всего, по причине того, что у меня установлен Cyanogenmod, вместо выключения экрана, появляется меню с выбором действия (выключить, перезагрузить...). Однако этот способ также пробуждает устройство, когда экран выключен.

Версия андроид: 4.2.2

Устройство: Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 7.0 p3100

Comment: Пример хорошего и правильно оформленного вопроса. Мой upvote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Эмуляция нажатия кнопки `POWER` работает верно, но метод `Process.waitFor()` там лишний. Правильный код:

```
Process mSU = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(mSU.getOutputStream());
os.writeBytes("input keyevent 26");
os.flush();
os.close();
```

*Для эмуляции кнопок этим способом, требуются права супер пользователя.*

Коды кнопок можно получить из констант класса [`KeyEvent`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html%22%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%8B%20%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BA%22). Здесь используется команда ADB `adb shell input keyevent 'код кнопки'`.

Answer (score 0):

Идея раз. Если работает `KEYCODE_WAKEUP`, то попробуйте `KEYCODE_SLEEP` и `KEYCODE_POWER`.

Идея два.

```
DevicePolicyManager mDPM = (DevicePolicyManager)getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);
mDPM.lockNow();
```

Идея три (чит, это не выключение экрана).

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams params = getWindow().getAttributes();
params.screenBrightness = 0;
getWindow().setAttributes(params);
```

Comment: Ой, я это первым делом перепробовал, если бы всё было так просто, то не писал бы сюда. Бьюсь уже несколько дней, всё бестолку. Может быть вы знаете ещё способы?

Comment: @Максим ну вот пара идей еще, с просторов интернета =)

Comment: Компьютера нет, если вы оставили ссылки, то боюсь я их не вижу...

Comment: Я проапдейтил ответ выше.

Comment: Слеповат я стал. Второй способ выдаёт ошибку, третий не робит, наверное потому, что я работаю из InputMethodService. Только что попробовал добавить подобную кнопку в LMTLauncher, просто выбрал опцию "дополнительные команды->key", там прописал 26, кнопка работала как надо. Есть ещё такой метод в ADB "sendevent", там вроде бы можно инициализировать нажатие клавиши и её подъём, вот только я не знаю как им пользоваться.

Comment: @Максим: sendevent device type code value, например, sendevent /dev/input/event4 1 116 1

Comment: Примеров в интернете я уже начитался, но вот за что отвечают первая и вторая единицы, что находится в "event4" (да, я пытался их прочесть, но похоже что настоящие файлы скрыты где-то в системе, а те что я нашёл, весили 0 КБ и открыть я их не мог).? Есть ли где-нибудь информация по этим "eventX"?

Comment: @Максим Ну вот тут варианты, как перечислить подключенные устройства http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6990978/how-can-i-know-which-of-the-dev-input-eventx-x-0-7-have-the-linux-input-stre

Comment: Пишет что подключено десять устройств. Input4 – accelerometer...

Comment: Я тут подумал, проблема может быть вот в чём, когда я посылаю в ADB "input keyevent 26", система думает что я зажал клавишу. Возможно потом нужно вызвать какой либо метод, который отменит нажатие или сообщит системе, что клавиша была отпущена.

Comment: Ур-ра! Проблема заключалась в том, что я зачем-то использовал метод Process.waitFor(); и система не получала ACTION_UP, теперь всё работает как надо, как всегда я наложал в коде... Спасибо что откликнулись, буду внимательнее.